# Как правильно составить query с предикатом LIKE , но для всех полей одно таблицы

Tags: sql, запрос

Как правильно составить query запрос с предикатом LIKE , но для всех полей одной таблицы
Сам запрос

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM название_таблицы WHERE 'ПОКАЗАТЬ ЧТО ВСЕ ПОЛЯ ДАННОЙ ТАБЛИЦЫ' LIKE  '%ЧТО ИЩЕМ%'";
```

По аналогии как знак *(звёздочка) после SELECT.
Запрос примерный конечно, размещён для понимая. Хочется в ответе такой же легко читаемый код.

Хоть одна колонка может совпадать.

Comment: Укажите во-первых СУБД, а во-вторых, должна ли **хоть одна** колонка совпадать, или строго **все** колонки?

Comment: Конкатенировать все проверяемые поля, используя в качестве разделителя символ, отсутствующий в шаблоне поиска.